# Customising Bootstrap grid to 840px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a customised version of Bootstrap from here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

The only setting I changed was @gridColumnWidth from 60px to 50px to give me an 840px grid system rather than the standard 960px.

However, I am encountering problems at screen-width 768px such as the top-fixed navbar is breaking:

[image]

With the default settings, the navbar remains fixed:

[image]

Can anybody advise why this is happening and which other settings should be adjusted? I chose 840px as I need a fairly narrow design consisting of 3 equal-width columns. In this case, 280px including gutters.

Comment: Missing stylesheet? What does the Chrome Inspector say?

Comment: Good point. bootstrap-responsive.css isn't included in the zip-file when you customise and download from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html. I tried linking to this file and it solves the problem but only (I think) because it resets the grid to the default system.

Comment: It's hard to inspect a page only by it's screenshot. Can you provide a link to the live website?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a fixed grid of an arbitraty width using a fixed container and fluid rows.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sonic1980/chKWm/

**HTML:**

```
<div id=container class=container>
    <div class=row-fluid>
        <div class=span4>4</div>
        <div class=span4>4</div>
        <div class=span4>4</div>
    </div>
...
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 500px;   <-- put here your desired width. 
                        You can also play with max-width and min-width
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hum !   I did not find any explicit option on the width of the page (this is a problem that I have already met),

by cons, which is provided in this customization is - in paragraph Responsive - to choose between 3 sizes:

- Large (> 1200px)
- Tablet to Desktop (767-979px),  and
- Narrow tablet and below (<767px). ..

Comment: You can configure any dimension of the layout under "Grid System"